# Invoking static methods from another class

Tags: java, math, calculator

So I've spent the last couple days working on this program, and I've hit a roadblock. I am trying to make a calculator that uses specific programs with user input to calculate the Surface area or Volume of multiple shapes. You might recognize this as project 8.5 from the Horstmann java concepts book.

I don't know how to call the methods from one file to another, and need to figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class p85SantoCharlie{


  public static double sphereVolume(double r){

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter your Radius");
   r = in.nextDouble();

   double volume = (4/3) * Math.PI * r * r * r;

   System.out.println(volume);

   return volume;

   }

  public static double sphereSurface(double r){

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter your Radius");
   r = in.nextDouble();

   double surface = 4 * Math.PI * r * r ;

   System.out.println(surface);

   return surface;

   }

  public static double cyliderVolume(double r, double h){

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your Radius");
r = in.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Please enter your Height");
h = out.nextDouble();

double volume =  Math.PI * r * r * h ;

System.out.println(volume);

return volume;

   }

  public static double cylinderSurface(double r, double h){

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your Radius");
r = in.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Please enter your Height");
h = out.nextDouble();

double surface = 2 * Math.PI * r * r * h ;

System.out.println(surface);

return surface;

   }  

  public static double coneVolume(double r, double h){

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your Radius");
r = in.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Please enter your Height");
h = out.nextDouble();

double volume = Math.PI * r * r * h / 3 ;

System.out.println(volume);

return volume;

    }

  public static double coneSurface(double r, double h){

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your Radius");
r = in.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Please enter your Height");
h = out.nextDouble();

double surface = Math.PI * r * (r + Math.pow(( r * r + h * h), .5));

System.out.println(surface);

return surface;
   }
}
```

And here is the main file:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class p85SantoCharlieMain{

   public static void main(String[] args){

   p85SantoCharlie mainProgram = new p85SantoCharlie();

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please select a shape");

   System.out.println("your choices are: Sphere, Cylinder, and Cone");

   String answer1 = in.next();

   String answer1Caps = answer1.toUpperCase();

   System.out.println("Fantastic! now select a formula");

   System.out.println("your choices are: surface area or volume");

   String answer2 = in.next();

   String answer2Caps = answer2.toUpperCase();



   if (answer1Caps.equals("SPHERE")&& answer2Caps.equals("SURFACE AREA")){

      mainProgram.sphereSurface();

   }



   } 

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get your question. You're calling that other "program" already (the parameter is missing however): `mainProgram.sphereSurface();`

Answer (score 1):

If the methods are static you can call them using the class name

```
p85SantoCharlie.sphereVolume(1.1);
```

And if they aren't static initialize new class instance and use it to call

```
p85SantoCharlie p = new p85SantoCharlie();
p.sphereVolume(1.1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

First, all of your calculation methods in `p85SantoCharlie` are `static`. You don't need an instance of `p85SantoCharlie` to invoke them. You should get rid of the line where you do `new p85SantoCharlie()` and invoke your methods like

```
p85SantoCharlie.sphereVolume(r);
```

Second, you have declared your calculation methods as taking parameters, but you don't know those parameters when you invoke them. For example, `sphereVolume()` is declared as taking `double r`. But you don't know the value of `r` until you read it in within the `sphereVolume()` method. So that can't work. You need to change your `main` method to ask for the radius, then pass it to `sphereVolume` as shown above.

Third, all of those `Scanners`! Get rid of them all except for the one in `main`. You will be passing in the value of `r` (or whatever) when you invoke the calculation method. Just use what is passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, unreadable code.

Java's an object-oriented language.  I would expect that you'd start with a `Shape` interface:

```
public interface Shape {
    double surfaceArea();
    double volume();
}
```

I'd expect to see subclasses for different types that would do the calculation appropriately.  Here's a Sphere implementation:

```
public class Sphere implements Shape {
    private final double radius;

    public Sphere(double radius) {
        if (radius <= 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("radius must be positive");
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double surfaceArea() {
        return 4.0*Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius;
    }

    public double volume() {
        return 4.0*Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius*this.radius/3.0;
    }
}
```

Here's a Cylinder implementation:

```
public class Cylinder implements Shape {
    private final double radius;
    private final double height;

    public Cylinder(double radius, double height) {
        if (radius <= 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("radius must be positive");
        if (height <= 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("height must be positive");
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double surfaceArea() {
        return 2.0*Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius + this.radius*this.height;
    }

    public double volume() {
        return Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius*this.height;
    }
}
```

I'd expect to see your driver class interact with Shape objects to solve the problem.

You'll want to consider a virtual constructor/factory for `Shape`, because you won't want to clutter your code with `if/else` constructs.

My opinion: Object-oriented programming was invented to solve two problems:

1. Encapsulation of state and behavior into a single abstract data type.
2. Inheritance and polymorphism to eliminate if/else and switch statements.

Do not clutter your code with "if sphere and area" kinds of decisions.  Let polymorphism handle it for you.

New programmers tend to spend too much time worrying about user interfaces.  Concentrate on the functionality and get that working first.  Don't create a bunch of text question/answer code and leave the meat of the problem undone.